# how to define my own customized image preprocess function when using keras.preprocess.image.ImageDataGenerator

Tags: image-processing, deep-learning, keras

I found there are some image preprocess functions that are not included in `keras.preprocess.image.ImageDataGenerator`

So how can I add my own customized preprocess function to `ImageDataGenerator`, like changing brightness, saturation, color jittering, image cropping etc.

Comment: This is a very good thread on github: https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/3338. Please refer it.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. I wonder if there is any official interface that can allow me to combine my preprocess function with ImageDataGenerator?

Answer (score 5):

Actually - you could specify your own preprocessing function and set it in your [`ImageGenerator`](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/#ImageDataGenerator). For example:

```
def preprocessor(image):
    # perform augmentations here
```

and then:

```
image_generator = ImageDataGenerator(..., preprocessing_function=preprocessor)
```

Comment: Thanks. This means you can do your own preprocess before ImageDataGenerator. Can preprocess_function be a list of functions rather than a single function?

Comment: You could define function which applies a sequence of preprocessing functions :)

Comment: @AbrahamBen - was my answer helpful?

Answer (score 2):

Just make your preprocessing function and pass it as a parameter to `preprocessing_function` function of `ImageDataGenerator`. You can also pass more than one preprocessing functions in your `ImageDataGenerator` by calling all of them inside one `preprocess()` function.

If you are trying to pass just one preprocessing function :-

```
def preprocess():
    # operations
```

If you are trying to pass more than one preprocessing functions :-

```
def preprocess():
    another preprocess_function()
        # operations
```

Then just pass that preprocess() in ImageDataGenerator :-

```
train_gen = ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=preprocess())
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def get_random_eraser(p=0.5, s_l=0.02, s_h=0.4, r_1=0.3, r_2=1/0.3, v_l=0, v_h=255, pixel_level=False):
    def eraser(input_img):
        img_h, img_w, img_c = input_img.shape
        p_1 = np.random.rand()

        if p_1 > p:
            return input_img

        while True:
            s = np.random.uniform(s_l, s_h) * img_h * img_w
            r = np.random.uniform(r_1, r_2)
            w = int(np.sqrt(s / r))
            h = int(np.sqrt(s * r))
            left = np.random.randint(0, img_w)
            top = np.random.randint(0, img_h)

            if left + w <= img_w and top + h <= img_h:
                break

        if pixel_level:
            c = np.random.uniform(v_l, v_h, (h, w, img_c))
        else:
            c = np.random.uniform(v_l, v_h)

        input_img[top:top + h, left:left + w, :] = c

        return input_img

    return eraser


    datagen = ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=get_random_eraser(v_l=0, v_h=1), zoom_range=0.0, horizontal_flip=False)
```

Comment: This function is working for me it is a random eraser in side "eraser" function ucan change to your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

In order for Marcin solution to work for me, I had to define the preprocessing_function in the ImageDataGenerator:

> train_datagen=ImageDataGenerator(
>       ...
>       preprocessing_function= **preprocessor(image).all()**,
>   ...
>       )